# What is the exact use(s) of "feel like"?

Tags: grammar

As I have concluded "I feel like" can have two different meanings. One is "to have a desire for", and the other is "feel as if" or simply just "feel".
I just want to know how common(or correct) is the second meaning?

For examples:
What is the difference between

1. "I feel like I am not able to eat more"

and

2. "I feel that I am not able to eat more"

and

3. "I feel as if I am not able to eat more"?

Is the first sentence correct at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All are idiomatic, and mean the same thing, but you should ask "what is the **difference** between..." No. 1 is casual; no. 2 and 3 are more formal;

Comment: Oh, you right it's "**difference**". Thanks